# Redirecting to landing page or home page index based on User Group

Tags: php, javascript, html, joomla

I tried Googling and using forums.joomla.org, because I wanted to make sure I wasn't wasting people's time on here, but unfortunately I have had no luck. Here's my issue:

For my website, I have both a landing page which only has the link to register for free to become a member, and a proper index page which users access after they become registered. I set up the landing page as kanadax.ca/ because I want people to land there when they first come to the page. My real index page is located at kanadax.ca/index.php. However, now when users are already logged in and they click on the website logo to go to the root domain, they get a page not found error.

So what I want to do is:
- If it's a non-registered guest user, have the logo redirect to the landing page located at kanadax.ca/.
- Once a user becomes registered, anytime they go to kanadax.ca/index.php it should redirect to example.com/index.php.

Basically I'm looking for conditional redirecting based on user groups. Any ideas?

Now obviously I would actually prefer example.com/ url as main index page rather than the less attractive example.com/index.php but that's a second step after I fix the redirection. I believe it can be done with .htaccess but with the more complicated landing page - index page structure that I have for guest and registered users I think it may be a bit difficult. However, please do give feedback if you have any in this area as well.

I should mention I'm not super comfortable with php but I'm happy to try any suggestions if you'd like to give me a step by step. After all, my first goal in making this website is to learn!

Thanks a heap!

PS if necessary, I'm happy to provide a test account so you can play around with the website yourselves.

**Edit:

Hey @Adam, I really appreciate the input and the step by step, it's exactly what I needed. Now, I have put the first section at the beginning of index.php, however for the latter part, I'm not quite sure where to put it. When I search for anything logo related within index.php, two separate sections come up:

```
// Logo file or site title param
if ($this->params->get('logoFile'))
{
  $logo = '<img src="'. JURI::root() . $this->params->get('logoFile') .'" alt="'. $sitename .'" />';
}
elseif ($this->params->get('sitetitle'))
{
  $logo = '<span class="site-title" title="'. $sitename .'">'. htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('sitetitle')) .'</span>';
}
else
{
  $logo = '<span class="site-title" title="'. $sitename .'">'. $sitename .'</span>';
}
```

and

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="header-inner clearfix">
          <a class="brand pull-left" href="http://www.kanadax.ca/index.php/anasayfa">
            <?php echo $logo;?> <?php if ($this->params->get('sitedescription')) { echo '<div class="site-description">'. htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('sitedescription')) .'</div>'; } ?>
          </a>
          <div class="header-search pull-right">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-0" style="none" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

second part being under header. Do you think either of these is the right section? If so, should I delete what is in there and replace with your suggestion, or keep it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your template index.php file in the following way:

1. Add this somewhere at the begin of the code

   ```
   $user = JFactory::getUser();
   if(JFactory::getUser()->id)
   {
       //link to page for registered users 
       $link =  JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3');
   }else{
       //link to page for default users 
       $link =  JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1');   
   }
   ```
2. In the place where the logo should be displayed

   ```
   <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
       <img src="images/path_to_image_name"/>
   </a>
   ```

And that is it!
Latter when you are more familiar with Joomla and PHP you may create a custom module instead of injecting the template directly.

Comment: Don't mean to create unnecessary noise but I wasn't sure editing the original question with @Adam would notify you so posting a quick message :) Still trying to learn the etiquette of stackoverflow!

Comment: f. yeah I had to struggle a bit but finally I managed to implement your solution and it works beautifully. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to hack anything, you could also try sticking some redirect code in a custom html module in a debug or other position, but use Advanced Module Manager to only load it for guests or only load it for logged in users. You can do all kinds of tricks with AMM to load and not load things based on a zillion parameters.

Adam's answer is cleaner, but some people are really hesitant to hack their template (or if it's a commercial template it might be really messy to find the right spot to put the code in).

You can read more about AMM here:
http://www.nonumber.nl

Comment: Brian thank you for your input as well. I'm actually happy to try the code version because I'd really like to get more comfortable with coming up with similar solutions myself in the future, but I'll bookmark for the future!